# Nuxt 3 - how to add Vue3TouchEvents

Tags: vuejs3, touch, nuxtjs3

I writing Nuxt 3 application and I wonder if it possible to add touch events to it.

If I try as plugin with

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue3TouchEvents from 'vue3-touch-events'

Vue.use(Vue3TouchEvents)
```

I have and error `Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/....../node_modules/vue/dist/vue")'.ts(2339)`

If this library can not (or should not) be added - what would be a better way to handle touch events

Comment: Actually `Vue.use` is the vue2 way. In vue3 you need to [call the `use` function from the app instance](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html). I don't know why the plugin readme recommends the old way

Answer (score 0):

Solution for `nuxt 3`
create `vue3-touch-events.ts` in the root of the `plugins` directory then is use `nuxtApp.vueApp.use` because according to [nuxt documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins)  about
vue plugins registration:

```
import Vue3TouchEvents from "vue3-touch-events";
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Vue3TouchEvents)
})
```